# adding the android environment to eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I know that my problem is a very common one , actually I found a lot of people asking about it , but non of the provided solutions worked for me .
I followed the following steps :
1- Installed eclipse for java.
2- installed ADT .
3- installed the SDK
now when I open eclipse I create new android project but it gives me errors without even writing any code .
"R cannot be resolved to a variable"
I have read somewhere that I should choose the location of the sdk , but I can't find the option that allows me to do so .

Also when I open the properties I find that android is there , but I can't find the sdk manager or any of the buttons that should appear in the menu and are related to android.

I would appreciate it if anyone can help me with this , because I have to write an android code and I have one day left .

NOTE : THIS IS NOT HOMEWORK , I need to write some code for a test in my research , and I was asked to do it before two days only ,I've tried and I couldn't solve it alone.

Comment: Last minute homework?

Comment: no no I'm doing a research and at the last moment my supervisor decided to do some testings in this semester which is about to end , so I have to finish coding for the test in one day .

Comment: did you try clean build?

Comment: this option is not available now !

Comment: did you try to use the adt bundled with eclipse provided by android ?

Comment: I have downloaded it and extracted it inside the folder which has the eclipse.exe but it didn't work !

Comment: Try [this](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html). A completely fresh install with everything you need built in.

Comment: I think that I have downloaded this , I think I need away to tell eclipse where is this file any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution I will post in case someone faced a similar problem :
1- first go to windows->customized perspective
2-choose the tab command groups availability and click on the sdk manager .
3- from the sdk manager choose to install Android SDK build-tools.

after installing it , the error should be gone .